# In Inno Setup Scripting, how to check windows version and copy corresponding files

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I already know how to copy files in [Files] section, and I could check windows version in [Code] section.
But I don't know how copy correct files after checking version.
e.g. Windows 8.1 -> copy file A and B
     Windows 10 -> copy file B and C

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck

Comment: Thanks Sertac! You could copy the sample code to answer

Comment: @SertacAkyuz `Check` function is an overfill for this. You can use `MinVersion` parameter, as my answer to the duplicate question shows.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl what is "overfill" mean?

Comment: @Assam Sorry, I've meant *"overkill"*.